# Create a batch (.bat) file to move to a specific directory and output (echo) all files listed?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting

Create a bat file to move to a specific directory and output (echo) all files listed?

My current setup:

```
cd %CD%\src\main\orders
echo %dir%
```

I need to apply the following:

1. Extend upon the current directory; \src\main\orders is the
   extension.
2. Then print the files listed in the full path / directory.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) line seems capable of doing what you've laid out in your question.

```bat
@CD /D "src\main\orders" 2>NUL&&Dir /B/A-D
```

Open a Command Prompt window and enter both `CD /?` and `Dir /?` to find out how those two commands are used.

*You can remove the first character, `@` if running the command from the Command Prompt.*

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, you could do this:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "PATH TO DIRECTORY"`

If you want to view files in subfolders, add the `-Recurse` switch